# Evaluating function before its plotting

Tags: plotting, evaluation, hold

Suppose I want to plot a function $f(x,y)$ but first need to calculate its symbolic expression. An easy solution is to copy the output of my calculation by hand and then paste into `Plot` function. If I naively do this

```
f[x_,y_]:= 100*x^3+Tanh[y^2];
Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-10,10},{y, -20, 20}]
```

then it runs very slowly (for a much more complicated function I'm plotting). I think what's happenning is that instead of symbolically calcualte `f[x,y]`, Mathematica numerically calculates it.

Question: is there a way to delay `Plot` first and evaluate the function inside `Plot`? Maybe using `Hold`? But I don't see how I can evaluate the function first after holding.

Comment: Use `f[x_,y_] = 100*x^3+Tanh[y^2]` instead of `f[x_,y_] := 100*x^3+Tanh[y^2]`? Either that, or make a `Table` of values instead and use `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: Expanding on what @march said: please read up on the distinction between [immediate and delayed definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html). If you don't want to delay the definition, then just don't use a delayed definition (i.e., use an immediate definition instead).

Comment: Add the option `Evaluated->True` inside `Plot3D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Plot3D` has attribute `HoldAll`, so its arguments are not evaluated before variable substitution. You can override this with:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[f[x, y]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 20}]
```